# Getting jQuery to work in specific divs created with EJS template?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to collapse a row of columns rendered with EJS but I only want to collapse the columns inside the group that was clicked. I tried giving a class and an ID to the divs but when I try to collapse the class all the columns are collapsed even the ones that are not in that group and if I try to collapse an ID it will only collapse one of the columns.

I think that the jQuery is simple:

```
$('.groupName').on('click', function() {
      $('.col').fadeToggle();
});
```

But I still can't find a way with the ejs logic. 
My code:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 70px;margin-bottom: 30px;">
            <% groups.forEach(group => { %>
                <% if(group.active == true) { %>
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-start">
                        <div class="container">
                            <span id="group" class="groupName"><%= group.groupName %> </span>
                        </div>
                        <% apps.forEach(app => { %>
                            <% if (app.groupId == group.groupId && app.active == true) { %>                            
                                    <div class="col" id="app">
                                        <div class="card text-center" style="width: 20rem;height: 20rem;">
                                            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="<%= app.route %>"><strong><%= app.appName %></strong></a></h5>                                            
                                                    <p class="card-text text-muted giveMeEllipsis"><strong><%= app.appDescription %></strong></p>
                                                </div>                                       
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between ">
                                                        <a href="#" class="card-link mt-auto"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-auto"></i></a>
                                                        <p class="card-text text-muted"><strong><%= app.count %></strong></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                                                        <p class="card-text"><strong><%= app.appName %></strong></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            <% } %>
                        <% }) %>  
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% }) %>    
        </div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.col` selector is selecting the global class. In the case of the specific `.groupName` that is clicked, you first need to identify the parent in which the `.col` class is contained. Also, you should refer to the clicked element using `this`, so that your fade logic is encapsulated only within the scope of the element by which you clicked on. Try the following?

```
$('.groupName').on('click', function() {
    var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent(); // Two levels up in
                                                // order to select 
                                                // <div class="row d-flex justify-content-start">
    rowElement.find('.col').fadeToggle();
});
```

Made a little [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/550782/) for you in case it's still unclear.

Comment: Dang, It worked! Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle, it actually helped me a lot. It's something I would't even have thought of. Have a nice day!